# Blog index not going to wordpress folder

Tags: redirect

I just created a blog.mysite.com domain and installed WordPress. However, when I go to blog.mysite.com it isn't redirecting to WordPress - blog.mysite.com/wordpress. Should I move the contents of the /wordpress directory to my blog root folder or create an .htaccess redirect?

This is only going to be a wordpress blog so I assume I can move the files instead of creating a redirect, no?

Thank you! ;)

Comment: Do you want your blog to appear on - `blog.mysite.com/wordpress` OR just `blog.mysite.com`

Comment: If there is nothing else in the root, then I'd move the files there.

Comment: Only plesk-stats but I assume this won't conflict with wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the WordPress files in the root of the **subdomain** - that is, wherever your host's document root for `blog.mysite.com` is. In my case, that's `/public_html/blog`; but I assume that could be different from host to host.

I would recommend doing a fresh install, rather than just moving the files - unless you're comfortable with potentially manually editing the DB to change WordPress URL/Site URL settings.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) in Codex: [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install).

You don't have to move everything, just the `index.php` file needs to be copied to root and updated to point to your subdirectory install.